# Tkinter - function that force graph and label to update

Tags: python, tkinter, graph

I'm trying to create a window which contains a graph (created from points), and label depends on string variable who I can also change with a function that update them

The problem I faced is creating a function that force the graph and the label to update and show the new variables.
this is what I tried

> class gui:
>
> def **init**(self):
> self.root = None
> self.txt = None
>
> def vp_start_gui(self):
> self.**init**()
> self.root = tk.Tk()
> INSERT YOUR WHOLE CODE HERE"""
> data_cpu = {'Time': update_time(),
> 'CPU utilization': update_cpu()
> }
> df_cpu = DataFrame(data_cpu, columns=['Time', 'CPU utilization'])
>
> figure_cpu = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
> ax_cpu = figure_cpu.add_subplot(111)
> line_cpu = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure_cpu, self.root)
> line_cpu.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
> df_cpu = df_cpu[['Time', 'CPU utilization']].groupby('Time').sum()
> df_cpu.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax_cpu, color='b', marker='o', fontsize=10)
> ax_cpu.set_title('CPU utilization over time')
>
> lbl = tk.Button(self.root, text=self.txt, bd='2')
> lbl.pack(side='top')
>
> btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='REFRESH', bd='2',
> command=self.refresh)
>
> btn.pack(side='top')
> CREATE A BUTTON AND ITS command = refresh() which is defined at the bottom"""
> self.root.mainloop()
>
> def changeLabel(self, text):
> self.txt = text
>
> def refresh(self):
> self.root.destroy()
> self.vp_start_gui()
>
> def main(self):
> self.vp_start_gui()
> #self.changeLabel("second")
>
> a = gui()
> a.main()

Comment: Please paste the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please format as code block (the `{}` button) and fix the indentation.